# Swift: For loop - wait for animation to complete before iteration

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uibutton

I am trying to display a sequence of animations based on a shuffled array.

On my ViewController I have 4 UIButtons with tags (1,2,3,4).

I then have a shuffledArray

```
shuffledArray = [3,2,4,1]
```

I am looping through that array using a for loop and animating the background of the UIButton like so:

```
for square in shuffledArray {
        let btn = view.viewWithTag(square)
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.0, options:[], animations: {
            btn?.backgroundColor = .red
            btn?.backgroundColor = .black
            btn?.backgroundColor = .red
        }, completion: nil)
 }
```

However, this just makes the 4 squares all flash black at the same time.

Is there a way to run this loop but wait for each animation to fire first before iterating through to the next index of the array?

I tried using:

```
sleep(4)
```

and the end of the for loop but that seems to freeze my app and then again all 4 squares change at the same time.

## Side Note

This for loop is activated on a button click. After the for loop has ran I am generating a random number between 1 and 4 and then appending that to the shuffledArray. So it starts of:

```
 shuffledArray = [3]
```

then the second time it is

```
 shuffledArray = [3,2]
```

And the third

```
 shuffledArray = [3,2,4]
```

and so on....

The issue seems to only happen when the array contains more than 1 item.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this? **(NOT tested)**

```
var currentIndex = 0 
func animateNext() {
    if currentIndex < shuffledArray.count {  
        let btn = view.viewWithTag(shuffledArray[currentIndex])
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.0, options:[.autoreverse], animations: {
            btn?.backgroundColor = .red
            btn?.backgroundColor = .black
        }) { _ in
            self.currentIndex += 1
            self.animateNext()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The moment the shuffedArray gets two items it doest turn any of the squares black.

Comment: Resetting `currentIndex` to 0 before calling `animateNext()`

Comment: Also, try using `.autoreverse` to create a better blinking effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the delay property, like this:

```
for (index, square) in shuffledArray.enumerated() {
        let btn = view.viewWithTag(square)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: index, options:[], animations: {
            btn?.backgroundColor = .red
            btn?.backgroundColor = .black
            btn?.backgroundColor = .red
        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

**UPDATED:**

- Try to combine animations by `CAAnimationGroup` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/caanimationgroup).
- Use `CAKeyframeAnimation` - for blink effects (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cakeyframeanimation)

Comment: This solution may be better as it is much simpler.

Comment: This works for the first one and then it seems to jump the other 3 together.

Comment: @JamesG Are you sure that each button has a correct tag?

Comment: @NikitaErmolenko yup. Just checked.

Comment: @JamesG Can you for testing increase the delay? Something like that: delay * 3. And check the animations in slow simulator mode.

Comment: @NikitaErmolenko ok, I tried this with the index * 3. The issue is that they next animation loads before the flash has finished. And the delay black fade  slower, so when array gets to around5 items the black squares are staying for long time.

Comment: @JamesG oh, just noticed it. Why do you change the `backgroundColor` for three times in the animation block? oO

Comment: @NikitaErmolenko to create a blink/flash effect.